# How can I Sum arrays lengths from arraylist Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can i sum arrays lenghts from arraylist, i want to get sum of string lenght from arrays and print the sum

the bug is in main

```
public class Listy {
public static void main(String[] Listy) {

    List<String[]> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList((["Pat"], ["Michał"],))
    System.out.println(getSumOfLenghts(a));




    public static int getSumOfLenghts(List<String[]> words) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (String[] currentarray:words) {
        sum += currentarray.length;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The syntax for array creation is `new String[] { "Pat" }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shmosel comment, you get the errors because you did not declared a array as java syntax, you have a list of String array:

I edited your code as below and it's work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<String[]> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.add(new String[]{"Pat", "Michal"});
    words.add(new String[]{"Pat 2", "Michal 2"});
    System.out.println(getSumOfLenghts(words));
}
```

**Edit:**
To answer your question on comment, I have create this example, that contains two function:

1. `getSumOfLenghts` this function return how much String in the list
2. `getSumOfEachStringLenghts` this function return the sum of all the String in the list.

   ```
   public class Listy {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String[]> words = new ArrayList<>();
       words.add(new String[]{"Pat", "Michal"});
       words.add(new String[]{"Pat 2", "Michal 2"});
       System.out.println(getSumOfLenghts(words));
       System.out.println(getSumOfEachStringLenghts(words));
   }

   public static int getSumOfLenghts(List<String[]> words) {
       int sumArrElem = 0;

       for (String[] currentarray:words) {
           sumArrElem += currentarray.length;
       }
       return sumArrElem;
   }

   public static int getSumOfEachStringLenghts(List<String[]> words) {
       int sumForEachElem = 0;

       for (String[] currentarray:words) {
           for (String s : currentarray) {
               sumForEachElem += s.length();
           }
       }
       return sumForEachElem;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay but how to sum not elements of arrays but lenghts??

Comment: you can get the String element and add the length in the sum variable

Comment: Could u show this as a code ?

Comment: okay but still after i run debugger i got error ,
Cannot find local variable 'currentarray', do u know whhy ?

Comment: @PatrykSzymańczyk see the edit

Comment: thank u, it's awasome and it's work and most important i understand that, thank u

Comment: @PatrykSzymańczyk happy to help, you're welcome